# Laravel 5.6 - Upload stored file to S3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.6 project which has images stored using the Storage facade.

I am trying to take an image that I have stored and move it to S3 storage like this..

```
$contents = Storage::disk('local')->url($image->filename);
$storagePath = Storage::disk('s3')->put("uploads", $contents, 'public');
```

This uploads a file to the S3 bucket called 'uploads' that contains the path to the file like this...

```
/storage/myimage.jpg
```

How can I upload the actual file instead of saving the path?

Comment: Change `->url()` to `->get()` and you will have the contents of the file.

Comment: This is all in the docs... https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-uploads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$contents = Storage::get('file.jpg');
```

[File System Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem)

Comment: I have been trying to do this like so $contents = Storage::get($image->filename); but I keep getting a file not found error

Comment: so the path is wrong that you stored in the database or the file name is different in folder and in database

Comment: Filename is correct, but I am confused where the path get's set. Does the Storage::get not automatically add the storage path?

Comment: Storage::get($file) it takes full path as well as only name of the file

Comment: @fightstarr20 can you see your file in storage/app/, if yes then try to hard code the name of the file in Storage::get($filenmae) and then try to get it contents.

Comment: Files are in storage/app/uploads/

Comment: can you try to store file with this         $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/uploads', $request->file->getClientOriginalName());
and also run this command if you have'nt run: php artisan storage:link

Comment: All sorted now, I needed to go back and change the way I was storing the files

Answer (score 0):

After adding `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`

You can do it like this:

```
$contents = Storage::get('file.jpg');
```

[File System Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem)